# getParcelableArrayListExtra issue. Program crashing

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist

I'm trying to pass an arraylist of objects to a new activity, I followed a tutorial and it looks as if I've done everything right but my program kept crashing. I've commented out the majority of the code to isolate the line that seems to be causing the crash and its the getParcelableArrayListExtra bit that seems to be the problem. Can anyone help?

New Activity:

```
public class DatabaseSearch extends ListActivity{
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    ArrayList<String> listrecipes = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.databasesearch);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        if (i != null) {
            ArrayList<mydata> data = i.getParcelableArrayListExtra ("com.example.MyPantry.array");
        }
    }
}
```

Bit of code from the old activity--
I don't know if it matters but the new activity is being called within a dialog box

```
    @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{   

    switch(id) {
    case 0:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setTitle("List all recipes that match over:")
        .setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (item)
                {
                case 0:
                    percentageselected = 25;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    percentageselected = 50;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    percentageselected = 75;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    percentageselected = 100;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        })
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                int whichButton)
                {
                    if (percentageselected == 0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please make a selection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DatabaseSearch.class);
                        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("com.example.MyPantry.array", array);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, 
                    int whichButton)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        })
        .create();

    }
    return null;
}
```

My objects inside the array I want to pass--

```
public class mydata implements Parcelable {

private int recipeID;
private int ingredientID;
private String check = "unchecked";
private int percentage = 0;


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel data, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      data.writeInt(recipeID);
      data.writeInt(ingredientID);
      data.writeString(check);
      data.writeInt(percentage);
}

    //Other functions
}
```

Lastly I have this class that the tutorial instructed me to make...

```
public class MyCreator implements Parcelable.Creator<mydata> {
@Override
public mydata createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new mydata(source);
}

@Override
public mydata[] newArray(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new mydata[arg0];
}
```

}

So I know it's quite a bit to look at but I'm just trying to be thorough. The problem starts to occur inside the if statement in the new activity.

Answer (score 0):

When just passing data between intents, you can just mark your classes as Serializable (by implementing the Serializable marker interface) and add them directly to the intent as extras without having to do all this work with parcelable (parcelable is really only needed when binding to services).

It's hard to say why you're getting the error without seeing a stack trace or the constructor for mydata that populates the class using the Parcel.

Comment: I would rather use Parcelable always, it is a Android's optimized way of doing Serializable. Yes, it is hard to implement but faster than Serializable. The more you take care in your code, the less runtime environment need to deal with to run.